# htaccess 301 redirect domain.com/dir/trackback/ to domain.com/dir/

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

As the title states, I've run into a few incoming traffic sources that are adding /trackback/ on the end of some of my URLs. The pages load fine due to my existing htaccess which grabs the dir name... But I don't want to generate tons of duplicate content with and without the /trackback/ addition. These incoming hits need to drop the /trackback/ off the end. What is the best way you would accomplish this without changing incoming links/sources?

I'm currently using php to check $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and redirect back to the same URL without /trackback/ but I'm sure htaccess would be much faster because it wouldn't need to process the php engine of my site twice...

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as off topic... I asked a question related to programming with php/apache/htaccess?

Comment: Voted to reopen it as it is a pretty generic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is a 301 redirect, which will flag the URL in most crawlers as if the URL they found (with /trackback/) permanently redirects to the version without. This would allow you to not have Google flag your content as duplicate.

You can do this using rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/trackback/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This will flag anything with /trackback/ at the end as a redirect to the page without.

**NOTE**: those hits are most likely bots looking for blogs with automated trackback acknowledgement in order to publish more links.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It works perfectly to remove the trailing /trackback/ from URLs and returns the 301 like I hoped. I am aware these are blog crawling bots from looking at the incoming traffic logs, but I hoped to keep everything as is from the incoming sources. This is the solution. Thank you.